# Renaming package name of a project

Tags: android, eclipse, package

I've usually used Eclipse refactoring tools to rename an Android project's package name. But not long ago I've discovered this functionality in Android Tools, it's called Rename Application Package. However, using it doesn't actually rename the folders of the project, the file system naming stays the same. Now the question is: how to rename the package properly? Is it enough to use Rename Application Package tool, are should I also use refactoring to rename the actual packages? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i didn't know about the renaming tool, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn't actually rename the folders of the project

and it shouldn't. Project folders have nothing to do with the package name. You can have different names for those two things. After you rename the package, you will have a problems with references to components in AndroidManifest.xml because most likely you have something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyAwesomeActivity"/>
```

Which means that your activity should be searched in the default package. But since you renamed package, you should have following:

```
<activity android:name="my.java.package.MyAwesomeActivity"/>
```

where `my.java.package` is actual package(project folders).

Comment: So if I just rename the package using Android Tools I can leave the file system as it is?

Comment: You can, but don't forget to update the references in manifest.

Comment: The tool handles it automatically. Seems like it's working, thank you!